# Proving convergence for a series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Let there be given that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$ is a convergent series and $a_{i}$ is not negative for every $i\in\mathbb{N}$.

And i want to prove that this series is also convergent (given above information):

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2a_{n}+1}{(a_{n})^2+n^2}$.

So, i was thinking to transform it,by changing it's value into bigger and proving with "sandwich" criteria, but i am stuck at how to tranform it.
Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Note that since $a_n\geq0$, you easily have $$\frac{n^2a_n+1}{n^2+a_n^2}= \frac{n^2a_n+1}{n^2(1+a_n^2/n^2)}\leq\frac{n^2a_n+1}{n^2}=a_n+\frac{1}{n^2}.$$ Now just use a comparison test.

Comment: +1, though if I'm not mistaken, the first inequality should be an equality.

Comment: @user3002473: You're correct; I had initially planned on skipping the writing of that step but second-guessed myself and went ahead and put it up there. I'll change it now, thanks.